# (React-Select hooks) How can I update state using Select's onChange render prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I've tried quite a few methods but I have not been able to get onChange to work. I'm working on a search-bar component that makes a fetch call after the user has not changed the search bar input for 3 seconds, but I am having issues changing the userSearchInput state hook which fires the api call in useEffect. Here is a minimized version of the code:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function SearchBar() {
  const [userSearchInput, setUserSearchInput] = useState("");
  const [searchSuggestions, setSearchSuggestions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchSuggestions = async (searchInput) => {
      console.log("api called");
      const searchSuggestions = await fetch(
        'API STUFF'
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setSearchSuggestions(data.quotes);
        });
    };

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (userSearchInput !== "") {
        searchSuggestions("test");
      }
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [userSearchInput]);

  const handleSearchInputChange = (event) => {
    setUserSearchInput(event.target.value);
    console.log("input changed");
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={searchSuggestions}
      value={userSearchInput}
      placeholder="Search a ticker"
      onChange={handleSearchInputChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select has value of object containing "label" and "value"

also, react select already returning value in an argument of function so all you have to do is to use it

```
const handleSearchInputChange = (selectedOptionObj) => {
    setUserSearchInput(selectedOptionObj);
    console.log("input changed");
  };
```